# rsyslog: Discarding Unwanted Messages

Tags: rsyslog

I have a problem with rsyslog, "stop" doesn't discard messages.

```
cat /etc/rsyslog.d/10-ignore-user.conf
```

> if $msg contains "" then stop

If I replace "stop" by "/tmp/rsyslog.log" the filtering is ok, I see all message of "username"

For information:

- CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core)
- rsyslog-8.24.0-12.el7.x86_64
- I don't change /etc/rsyslog.conf
- I have another conf file by default    /etc/rsyslog.d/99-listen.conf

> $SystemLogSocketName /run/systemd/journal/syslog

I have the same problem with redhat [solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snwZy.png)

https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1564823

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't see any reference to the "username" you mentioned in the text of your question (the fourth row), inside the rsyslog directive (where I see only an `if` with a condition matching an empty string). Please, add details... starting from what EXACTLY you're trying to achieve. (BTW: IMHO a proper configuration of `rsyslog` is not exactly an easy task. Keep this in mind, while you handle it).